# Flutter IOS just_audio not playing when phone in silent mode

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, just-audio

I am developing an audio app. To play the various audio files I am using the just_audio package:

[Just_Audio](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio)

It works fine on Android phones, but with iPhones when the phone is set to silent mode it is not playing any sound. Is there anyway to fix this that anyone has come across?

My code set up is very simple:

I declare the player:

```
final _player = AudioPlayer();
```

Set the url:

```
setAudioUrl(widget.mediaItem.itemUrl);
```

And play:

```
await _player.play();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Carson

Comment: I am also using the same package but I am not able to find an audio streaming position and complete audio duration... can you please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added the following to my /ios/Runner/AppDelegate.swift file (inside didFinishLaunchingWithOptions) which fixed the issue - for anyone else interested.

```
do {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *){
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, mode: AVAudioSessionModeDefault)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: I am also using the same package but I am not able to find an audio streaming position and complete audio duration... can you please help?

Comment: Check the answer to this ticket, it contains what you are looking for :       https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60165915/flutter-just-audio-playbackevent

Comment: Adding this code block isn't working for me, in silent mode sound is not playing as expected

Answer (score 2):

You can get the desired behaviour by setting your app's AVAudioSession category to `playback` via the [audio_session](https://pub.dev/packages/audio_session) package.

However, note that as of just_audio 0.4.0, this will actually be done for you by default. If you need to change the default, you can still do that via the audio_session package.